# Android equivalent to document and cache directory

Tags: android, ios, porting

I have a question regarding the predefined directories in android.

In my apple iOS app I use the following two directories:

```
//document dir for user files that need backup
NSString *d = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex: 0];
//cache dir for re-downloadable data
NSString *c = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Now I want to do the same in android, but I am not sure, how it is meant to be used there. My guess are these two functions, but some confirmation or redirection if wrong would be great.

```
String d = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String c = Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

Another point is, that both directories will contain several hundred megabytes, so maybe I need to use external storage for both? The cache dir is purged on iOS when the device needs more space. Is there a similar mechanism in android?

Comment: cache is purged on device restart. or if the user goes into Settings > applications > All application > Sepcific app > Clear cache.

Comment: Ouch, thx for pointing that out. I thought more of a permanent storage that can be wiped when needed, because the app is supposed to work offline with the downloaded content too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what version of Android is your minimum supported, you should look at:

```
Context#getExternalCacheDir()
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir()

and

```
Context#getExternalFilesDir(String)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

So to use these in an activity, you would just call:

```
File cacheDir = getExternalCacheDir();
```

or from a fragment:

```
File cacheDir = getActivity().getExternalCacheDir();
```

Android does not guarantee that the cache dir will get purged at any given time.  It is your responsibility to do that.

For a quick reference on what you should do with a cache dir on android, see this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()

Comment: That looks better, thanks. Level 8 API is not a problem for me either. So I should just use context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() for user-data and context.getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() for re-downloadeable data, and both are on the SD card because the internal memory is limited?

Comment: Correct.  However, SD card is also potentially limited.  Just make sure you set a reasonable maximum size to your cache.